# Convert Layer to Shapefile without losing Feature definitions

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, tableau

I have created a worldmap with custom defined features, representing State/Zip-Code sales areas. I want to convert them into a Shapefile, so I can convert the Shapefile into a polygon definition file for usage in Tableau.

When I do the following conversion, I lose the Feature definitions:
- I select the layer I want to export
- I do a DXF export
- I run Dxf2Shp Converter (plugin) to convert the DXF to a SHP
- When I then convert the SHP file to a Polygon definition file, I lose the feature groupings/definition.

A different Polygon shape is created for each little Island. For example, Hawaii would be separated into many different individual polygon shapes, while in my QGIS features, they are all grouped together as one. Basically, I'm losing the Feature grouping and get different polygons for each geographical island.

Any idea how to change/correct this? Or is there a better way of converting a QGIS file into a Shapefile?

Comment: I'm not understanding how are you creating the worldmap. "Custom defined Features"? Is this done in QGIS? Or another software?

Comment: @AlexandreNeto What I mean is that I create features that deviate in terms of country/region/state borders (group states or split states to create custom regions). In QGIS indeed.

Comment: Most welcome Paul! I will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others.

Comment: From the answer, I now undestand what you were asking but your question is very confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Dissolve** function on a column which contains attributes relating to a specific area. This should combine all separated polygons, such as those of Hawaii, into a single polygon.